# World Bank COVID-19 API (Incomplete JSON)

Tags: json

World bank stood up a visualization tool at the link below. At the bottom of the page they have the relevant indicators and those data can be downloaded. When viewing the .csv or other styles, I see the complete data. But, when grabbing the JSON objects from the API I see only the "Arab World" and no other countries or data.

Anyone else able to grab the complete JSON data, perhaps I am making a mistake?

http://datatopics.worldbank.org/universal-health-coverage/covid19/?fbclid=IwAR3nkRHks2DcduwimcrSz5kVagvAJHGbK4QkxnKJyOSUb2Hqdo4-XIOuRJU

Answer (score 0):

I made my website with the below two APIs,but state wise detailed data is available for India only.You can explore more options on the site.

https://corona-virus-world-and-india-data.p.rapidapi.com/api

https://api.rootnet.in/covid19-in/stats/history